# inject cordova.js to hosted webapp - for cordova livereload

Tags: ios, angular, cordova

I am trying to implement a live reload mechanism for an angular-cordova application. My first approach was to host the angular web-application on my local machine and connect the cordova app to the webserver running on my machine. This is already working very fine. The only issue is, that the hosted web-app has obviously no access to the `cordova.js` and the `cordova_plugins.js`. The files can not be hosted on the web-server, as the web-app should decide if it's running in a web- or in a cordova-context:

```
if (!cordova) {
 initializeWeb()
} else {
 initializeCordova()
}
```

I already tried to inject the scripts into the UIWebView (on iOS)

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
```

in the `webViewDidFinishLoad` hook of the UIWebView. I already tried to inject the scripts within the `webViewDidStartLoad` hook. Do you guys have any thoughts to realise this? I am also open for completely new approaches, but please don't suggest using Ionic - as this will not fit for our use case.

Thanks in advance.